# Determining parent of sub-customer through IDS

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm syncing data with QBOE using the IDS API V2. I can't figure out how to determine if a customer is a sub-customer. if the `Bill With Parent` happens to be true, then it's a safe bet, but that's not a guarantee. It also doesn't include the parent id which is needed.

The output of a nested customer is looking like this. Do I need to query the server differently?

```
<Customer xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
  <Id idDomain="QBO">88</Id>
  <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-06-20T17:38:22-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-06-20T17:38:22-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <Name>sub client</Name>
  <Phone>
    <DeviceType>Primary</DeviceType>
    <FreeFormNumber>123-4566</FreeFormNumber>
  </Phone>
  <WebSite />
  <Email>
    <Address>tsdsf@fasdf.com</Address>
  </Email>
  <GivenName>sub</GivenName>
  <FamilyName>client</FamilyName>
  <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField">
    <DefinitionId>Preferred Delivery Method</DefinitionId>
    <Value>EMAIL</Value>
  </CustomField>
  <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="StringTypeCustomField">
    <DefinitionId>Resale Number</DefinitionId>
  </CustomField>
  <CustomField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="BooleanTypeCustomField">
    <DefinitionId>Bill With Parent</DefinitionId>
    <Value>true</Value>
  </CustomField>
  <ShowAs>sub client</ShowAs>
  <OpenBalance>
    <Amount>0</Amount>
  </OpenBalance>
</Customer>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a job associated with the customer? If so, then query for jobs

Comment: @JarredKeneally That doesn't quite solve the problem. I'm trying to fetch all top level customers to syncronise with my service. subCustomers/Jobs are being returned when I fetch all customers. If there is a way to fetch just top level customers, leave it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I just found the `IncludeJobs` option for the V2 customer filtering. It would be nice to just query once for all customers and jobs instead of 2 seperate queries, but this will work. Thanks @JarredKeneally. If you put together an answer, I'll still give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Query for all top level customers without jobs query for customers with `IncludeJobs` set to false. You will need to query jobs seperately.